# Is it possible or any way to show my ad at any apps in android OS when click apps my ad will show

Tags: android

Is it possible or any way to show my ad at any apps in android OS when click apps my ad will show. Basically I want to show html div when I click the apps and div will hold specific ad image and div hold close button when I close the button then appear the apps.

Thanks
Md. Mahbub Hasan

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
You can utilize Admob for your concern. Try using this.
https://developers.google.com/live/shows/15536011